# Getting key values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to extract the names of all keys from an array of objects keeping time complexity as n(One loop only). The array is as below:

```
var addressArray = [{"city":"New York"},{"country":"USA"},{"zip": 45677}];
```

I want to extract the below:

```
var addressKeys = ["city", "country", "zip"].
```

I am able to do the same by first looping through the array and then using a key in obj loop but that doesn't loo good. Alternatives are most welcome.

Comment: `addressArray ` is not an array, it is an object

Comment: Edited the array. It is an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

Use Object.keys to get the keys.

```
if (typeof Object.keys !== "function") {
    (function() {
        Object.keys = Object_keys;
        function Object_keys(objectToGet) {
            var keys = [], name;
            for (name in objectToGet) {
                if (objectToGet.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    keys.push(name);
                }
            }
            return keys;
        }
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From your definition `addressArray` is an object not an array.

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys array of an object.

```
var addressKeys = Object.keys(addressArray);
```

To support [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility), which does not support `Object.keys` you can use a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill)

Comment: @ArunPJony, I think this approach is slower because it has to create instance of `Object ` and do some OOP methods. Test at : http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in

Answer (score 2):

Use `for-in` loop to access each `key-value` pair and then push to new array: **(Recommended)**

```
for(var index in addressArray){
    addressKeys.push(index)
}
```

Another solution is:

```
var addressKeys = Object.keys(addressArray)
```

which is slower comparatively.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I switched []'s with {}'s:

```
var addressObject = {"city":"New York", "country":"USA", "zip": 45677};

var keys = [];

for(var address in addressObject)
{
    keys.push(address);
}

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: If I had a single object I would not have asked the question.

Comment: @JyotirmoyPan Your example has problems then. You need to update it with an array of objects you want to get the keys of.